# Cannot remove LVM snapshot

Tags: lvm, partition

I am running Debian 11, using LVM.
The root partition is /dev/mainvg/lvroot.
I created a snapshot of the root partition by doing `lvcreate -L5G -n bkp_lvroot -s /dev/mainvg/lvroot`.

My system was in this state for a few days.

Now I wanted to remove the snapshot, like so:

```
lvremove /dev/mainvg/bkp_lvroot
  Logical volume mainvg/bkp_lvroot in use.
```

Looks like the snapshot is in 'active' state, so I tried to deactivate it:

```
lvchange -an -v  /dev/mainvg/bkp_lvroot
Change of snapshot mainvg/bkp_lvroot will also change its origin mainvg/lvroot. Proceed? [y/n]: n
  Accepted input: [n]
  Logical volume mainvg/bkp_lvroot not changed.
```

I cannot set the root partition to deactivated, can I???

Also: The snapshot is not mounted,
and `lsof | grep  /dev/mainvg/bkp_lvroot` brings no results

My actual question is: How can I safely remove the snapshot?  (I don't know how, and I don't want to break my system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already checked if the snapshot is mounted, and if there is still some open files.
Turns out there is another way to check to see if something has a "hold" on the snapshot:
**Use the major and minor disk number with lsof**

```
user:/$ sudo dmsetup info -c | grep bkp_lvroot
mainvg-bkp_lvroot     254   3 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-BYqsUKtfOGMnR2
mainvg-bkp_lvroot-cow 254   2 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-BYqsUKtfOGMnR2-cow

user:/$ sudo lsof | grep "254,3"
grub-moun 430214  root    3r      BLK   254,3 0t37847040    250 /dev/dm-3

user:/$ sudo lsof | grep "254,2"
user:/$
```

Solution to my problem: grub-mount still accesses the snapshot